# StructureMap StructureMap.StructureMapBuildPlanException, avoiding ObjectFactory

Tags: c#, winforms, structuremap, cqrs

I stumbled upon a sample of CQRS using StructureMap https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555855/Introduction-to-CQRS

However there sample uses ObjectFactory, which I wanted to avoid.

```
var cmdHandler = handlers.Select(handler => 
    (ICommandHandler<T>)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(handler)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This code can be found in https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=555855 ->Utils->StructureMapCommandHandlerFactory.cs

I wanted to try out this example on WinForms but without ObjectFactory.
Unfortunatelly I get an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'StructureMap.StructureMapBuildPlanException' occurred in
>   StructureMap.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a build plan for concrete
>   type CQRS.Core.Commands.CreateItemCommand

My current configuration is

```
 private IContainer container;

 public StructureMapCommandHandlerFactory()
 {
     this.container = new Container(_ => {     
           _.For<ICommandHandler<CreateItemCommand>>().Use<CreateItemCommandHandler>();
           _.Policies.ConstructorSelector<ThingCtorRuleCommand>();
                });
 }



 public class ThingCtorRuleCommand : IConstructorSelector
 {
     public ConstructorInfo Find(Type pluggedType, DependencyCollection dependencies, PluginGraph graph)
     {
         if (!pluggedType.CanBeCastTo<Command>()) return null;
          var ctr = pluggedType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IRepository<DiaryItem>) });
         return ctr;
     }
 }


public class CreateItemCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateItemCommand>
{
    private IRepository<DiaryItem> _repository;

    public CreateItemCommandHandler(IRepository<DiaryItem> repository)
    {
         _repository = repository;
    }

    public void Execute(CreateItemCommand command)
    {
           ...
    }
}
```

and object instantiation:

```
var cmdHandler = container.GetInstance<CreateItemCommand>();
```

Questions:
1. How should I configure the structure map to get the object CreateItemCommandHandler?
2. I don't really understand how the object is instantiated with values?
Passing simple parameters to constructor is described here:
http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/passing-arguments-at-runtime/

but how do I pass repository object to

```
public CreateItemCommandHandler(IRepository<DiaryItem> repository)
{
     _repository = repository;
}
```

I hope somebody can help me a bit...

**EDIT:**

After some investigation, i've found the error. When changing the container configuration to this one:

```
    private IContainer container;

     public StructureMapCommandHandlerFactory()
     {
                _.For<ICommand>().Use<Command>();
                _.For<ICommandHandler<CreateItemCommand>>().Use<CreateItemCommandHandler>();
                _.For<IRepository<DiaryItem>>().Use(new Repository<DiaryItem>());
                _.Policies.ConstructorSelector<ThingCtorRuleCommand>();
     }
```

and object instantiation:

```
var cmdHandler = container.GetInstance<CreateItemCommandHandler>();
```

it works.

However, I still don't really understand how to pass values to constructor on initialisation.
As the ObjectFactory is obsoleted, it my solution the right one, or just one that it accidentally works? :)

**Edit 2**

I figured it out how to set parameters:

```
EventBus eventBus = new EventBus(new StructureMapEventHandlerFactory());
IEventStorage storage = new InMemoryEventStorage(eventBus);
Repository<DiaryItem> repository = new Repository<DiaryItem>(storage);

var cmdHandler = container.With<IRepository<DiaryItem>>(repository).With<IEventStorage>(storage).GetInstance<ICommandHandler<CreateItemCommand>>();
```

So

```
With<IRepository<DiaryItem>>(repository).With<IEventStorage>(storage)
```

does the trick.

More about it here: http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/passing-arguments-at-runtime/

Still one question I haven't answered myself yet: **As the ObjectFactory is obsoleted, it my solution the right one, or just one that it accidentally works? :)** Please help...